# How to redirect after login about TabbedPage in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have:

1. MainView.xaml

   ```
   <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        BackgroundColor="#fff"
        ...
     >
     <views:Page1 Title="Page1" IconImageSource="homeicon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
     <views:Page2 Title="Page2" IconImageSource="order" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
     <views:Page3 Title="Page3" IconImageSource="ads" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
     <views:Page4 Title="Page4" IconImageSource="usericon" BackgroundColor="#fff"/>
   </TabbedPage>
   ```

[image]

and i have 1 login page. After logging in, you will be redirected to Page4.

I use: `App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page4())`

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   App.Current.MainPage = new Page4();
}
```

However I don't show TabbedPage

[image]

How to show the list of Tabs below. Please help me with the solution. Thank you

**Update**
I try

```
On Log in => App.Current.MainPage = new MainView();

Log Out => App.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your page inside a navigation page. That should help you fix it.

Update:

In MainView.xaml.cs put this

```
public MainView(int index)
{
InitializeComponent();
SetPage(index);
}

void SetPage(int index) { CurrentPage=Children[index]; }
```

after login, do this

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView(3))
```

Comment: I try: App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page4()) ---> Thanks, However it still doesn't work

Comment: If you need the bottom bar to appear, then you have to do App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView()) and pass some parameter to indicate that you want to switch to the 4th page

Comment: Yes, In MainView I added 'CurrentPage = Children[3];' (when done logging in it goes here to be correct). However, when I just Load App, it jumps to Page4 --> I don't want this, it should only happen when I complete login. I have edit in App.xml.cs: 'MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView().Children[0]);' ---> But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Tabbed page works with children. If you want to have the bottom bar, then you SHOULD load the tabbed page and then switch to the 4th page WITHIN the tabbed page. The code that you posted above will simply take the 4th page and load it without the tabbed page.

Comment: Can you post your clear answer in the reply?

Comment: In MainView.xaml.cs put this 
`public MainView(int index)
{
InitializeComponent();
SetPage(index);
}

void SetPage(int index)
{
CurrentPage=Children[index];
}
`

after login, do this
`App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView(3))`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @NinaadaBellippady It's really good, thank you

Comment: @ChimDiTru Did it work? if it did, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that

Answer (score 0):

When you change App.Current.MainPage, you change the MainPage of the app for anything you put there so that page is the only page that exists in the app. Try to set your tabbed page there and you will have the tabbed page as the 'MainPage'.
Now that your MainPage is the Tabbed Page, you can change the Page that is shown using the code below (inside the TabbedPage):

```
CurrentPage = Children[3]; // 0, 1, 2, 3
```

You will notice that you can change between any ContentPage attached to the TabbedPage

There is access to the MainPage everywhere now using (App.Current.MainPage as TabbedPage) so it's easy to change the shown page from other places

Comment: Perhaps you are misunderstanding. I'm logged in on another Page (eg login.xaml) and it's not in the MainPage containing the TabbedPages. When I login successfully, I am redirected to 1 of the pages located in the MainPage. How can I use: CurrentPage = Children[3];